# Facebook connect and share application for website (like 9gag)

Tags: facebook, logging, share, facebook-apps

I'm creating a website where users can make reservations on certain restaurants, I want the whole page to be integrated with Facebook since you log in. And when the user makes a reservation Facebook will automatically post the reservation on the users Facebook so other may see it in their home page (just like an activity of 9gag).

Any help please!! I'm a programmer but it's the first time I try to integrate Facebook.

Comment: FB has its own API that you can use for that. You will need a dev token to do so.

Answer (score 0):

If you start with Facebook, this is where you should go:

> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/

For login:

> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/

Also read the terms and conditions of facebook, there are some important rules for apps.